# How exactly Nagios server communicates with remote nodes i.e which protocol does it use in agent and agentless settings?

Tags: apache-spark, monitoring, nagios, pagerduty

I installed Nagios Core and NCPA on a Mac. Implemented a few checks via custom plugins to understand how to use it. I am trying to understand the following:

1. Protocol that Nagios server actually use to communicate with NCPA agent and how exactly does NCPA return the result back to Nagios. Does it ssh into Nagios server and writes a file that server processes?
2. From application monitoring standpoint how can it be leveraged? Is it just to monitor that application is up and running (I read its not just for that it can do more but couldn't find any place where I could see how its actually implemented) or is there a restful API as well that we invoke from with in our application to send custom notification to Nagios server. I understand it might require some configuration at Nagios server end as well.
3. I came across Pager Duty and Sematext articles i.e [PagerDuty Integration](https://www.pagerduty.com/docs/guides/nagios-xi-integration-guide/) and [SemaText Nagios Alert Integration](https://sematext.com/docs/integration/alerts-nagios-integration/#in-nagios) where they have integrated their solution with Nagios I am trying to do something similar. Adding integration support for Nagios so that a user can utilise our applications UI to configure alerts/notification. For e.g. if a condition is met then alert or notify Nagios server to show a notification on its dashboard.
4. Can we generate an alert from within a spark streaming application based on a variable e.g. if its value is above a threshold or some condition is met send an alert to Nagios Server to display as notification on Nagios Dashboard. I came across a link where we can monitor status of a spark application but didn't find anything for something within a spark application.

I tried looking for answers to above questions but couldn't find anything useful or complete as such online. I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand above.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Nagios** is highly configurable, and can communicate across many protocols. **NCPA** can return **JSON** or **XML** data. The most common *agentless* protocol is probably **SNMP**. If you can read *Python*, look directly at the */usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ncpa.py* file to see what's up.
2. **Nagios** can check whether a system is running a service, how much resources it is consuming, etc... There is a restful **API**.
3. **Nagios** offers an application with a more advanced graphical interface called **Nagios XI**. Perhaps that is what you are after.
4. I bet you probably could, yeah. It might take some development work to get the systems to communicate though.